# C++ unexpected output

Tags: c++

I am a C++ beginner

I wonder if there is any chance you might be able to tell me why my code (below) produces unexpected output? It compiles fine.

./a.out produces 4.94066e-324 rather than 1000

Thanks very much. Esther

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

enum class OrderBookType{bid, ask};

class OrderBookEntry
{
    public:

OrderBookEntry(double price, double amount, std::string timestamp, std::string product, OrderBookType orderType)
{}
        double price;
        double amount;
        std::string timestamp;
        std::string product;
        OrderBookType orderType;

};




int main()
{



while(true)
{
OrderBookEntry order1{1000,0.02,"2020/03/17 17:01:24.884492","BTC/USDT",OrderBookType::bid};

std::cout << order1.price << std::endl;

return 0;`
```

Comment: Your constructor : `OrderBookEntry(...)` accepts a bunch of parameters but does nothing with any of them.

Comment: `OrderBookEntry(double price_, double amount_, string timestamp_, string product_, OrderBookType orderType_) : price{price_}, amount{amount_}, timestamp{move(timestamp_)}, product{move(product_)}, orderType{orderType_} {}`

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor is not initializing the values.

use [Initialiser list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) like this

```
OrderBookEntry(double price, double amount, std::string timestamp, std::string product, OrderBookType orderType)
    : price(price), 
      amount(amount), 
      timestamp(timestamp), 
      product(product), 
      orderType(orderType)
{   
}
```